# How can I set my textClock to phone's default time format?

Tags: java, android

I have my TextClock Set as the following:

```
<TextClock
                android:id="@+id/datetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:format24Hour="HH:mm"
                android:format12Hour="HH:mm"
                />
```

Right now even though my phone is defaulted to a 12 hour time, it's showing up as a 24 hour time.

I want to be able to set it to a 12 hour time zone but not permanently, only in regards to whatever my phone is set as. How can I do that?

EDIT:

I removed the format above but I am setting it again in the code like:

```
TextClock textClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.datetime);
        textClock.setFormat12Hour("HH:mm");
        textClock.setFormat24Hour("HH:mm");
```

Would this also affect the phone's time zone?

I want to remove the AM/PM from the textclock when a format is not set in XML.

Comment: i have deleted my answer i think i got your requirement wrong you just want to remove am/pm from the textclock is this correct or i am still getting this wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <TextClock
            android:format12Hour="hh:mm"
            android:format24Hour="kk:mm"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:shadowColor="#7fffffff"
            android:shadowRadius="3.0"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I used This code it is not showing me am/pm on my device.

Comment: Okay but what if I want to format my clock like above? That is, I want to remove the AM/PM?

Comment: Setproperty via code, taking reference of the clock is best way it gives you more control

Comment: If I set the property via code, would it affect the time format? no right?

Comment: does your issue solved or still facing the same problem thnaks.

Comment: what am I setting the time format to? The above doesn't link to anything I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64649/discussion-between-kala-j-and-piyush).

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Why lower case hh and what is kk?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
android:format24Hour="HH:mm"
android:format12Hour="HH:mm"
```

This will make it so it automatically sets the format to what your phone is

Comment: Okay but what if I want to format my clock like above? That is, I want to remove the AM/PM?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
TextClock textClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.datetime);
textClock.setFormat12Hour(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
android:format12Hour="hh:mm a" // 11:59 PM
android:format24Hour="HH:mm" // 23:59
```